# Add a label to a message in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to using google apps script. I wanted to create a script that queries the inbox for messages from a particular sender and assign them labels. But I could not find any api that would assign a label to a message.

Note : "Need to assign label to a message and not to a thread"

Is there an api or any method to achieve this using google apps script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with GAS, but you could try using the modify() method of Gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify?hl=ru

Gmail API is available as an Advanced Service in GAS that must be enabled first. In Script Editor, go to 'Resources' -> 'Advanced Google services..'

Comment: Any reason as to why GAS does not support labelling of messages?

Answer (score 0):

There is https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify.

The documentation is incomplete, but through trial and error I discovered that the way to use `Gmail.Users.Messages.modify` is to pass the body first, then the url parameters:

```
const body = {
  addLabelIds: labelsToAdd,
  removeLabelIds: labelsToRemove,
};
const userId = "me";
Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(JSON.stringify(body), userId, messageId);
```

To get the label ids, you can follow the quick start example, which also explains how to set up the AppScript: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script.